# Is there a Fix implementation running under mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, fix-protocol

Is there an implementation of the fix protocol running under mono (either free or commercial) ?

I found the following ones, but none indicates if the code it's mono compatible :

- [QuickFix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/)
- [VersaFix](http://www.assimilate.com/Products/VersaFix/)
- [Onixs](http://www.onixs.biz/selfConnect/dotnet)
- [B2Bits](http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/fix_engine.net.aspx)
- [RA-Cheetah](http://www.rapidaddition.com/index.asp?page=80)

Comment: you could always download one or more of them and find out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the 2 open sources solutions :

- QuickFix doesn't work on Mono because the .net bindings are developed in C++/CLI, which is not supported by Mono.
- VersaFix however does run under mono without any changes, and its performances are quite similar under both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: http://www.fixprotocol.org/discuss/read/adec4479

Other than this, there is nothing specifically designed **that I know of**, but it does look like each of the engines you mentioned does have a separate forum or mailing list you could try.

I can tell you that the way QuickFix is designed can be a real pain due to the way is uses identical classes in separate namespaces for each version of FIX.

Sorry dont have a better answer, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the MoMA tool provided by http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA. I took the first one you specified "QuickFix" and downloaded the Binary version and scanned it with MoMA. The result was 273 Method calls that are not implemented.

It may sound like a lot but just like compiler errors, you fix a couple of things and the number goes down fast, also you have good odds that the parts you need will be fine and with the source for QuickFix available you may be able modify the code as needed or just throw some try{...}catch wrappers around those problem functions that you do need to use.

Of course you can try the same thing on the other available products, I just tried the first one. I believe MoMA will also work on obfuscated code, so you could test it on trial versions too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into [Quickfix/N](http://quickfixn.org/about/about-us.html), which claims to be an open-source native .Net port of Quickfix, without native C++ bindings. In fact the API looks very similar to Quickfix/J (The java port). I will update this post if I find it not to be Mono-compatible.